# How to set flags for executable in a Dockerfile RUN command?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a Docker image from a dockerfile, wherein I have an executable file. I want to set some flags for the executable, as example: An executable file with a silent flag and a flag for a ressource file. How can I do this in a RUN command in a Dockerfile?

I have so far tried to do:
`RUN /bin/bash -c 'PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE -i silent -f ressourceFile.properties'`,
this just returns an exit code of non-zero 1.

If I try to start the intermediate container from the layer before, and run the command with a `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash -c 'PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE -i silent -f file.properties'` . 
It gives me

```
-i: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-i: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have tried to run it as

`RUN 'PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE -i silent -f ressourceFile.properties'`
with the same result

And I have also tried to convert the RUN command to exec form per [Dockers documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#run)

`RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE", "-i", "silent", "-f", "file.properties"]`

but then it is unable to catch the flags.

Currently my dockerfile looks like this, with redacted executable:

```
FROM perl

COPY EXECUTABLE.bin ressourceFile.properties /tmp/

RUN chmod +x /tmp/EXECUTABLE.bin
RUN /bin/bash -c '/tmp/EXECUTABLE.bin -i silent -f /tmp/ressourceFile.properties'

# For debug purposes
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Expected result should be that the executable runs with the correct flags set and the path to the file.properties file correctly set. Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Can't you simply do `docker exec -it container PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE -i silent -f file.properties`? Try with `ls`: `docker exec -it container ls -A -l -h`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I would like to be able to install it in the dockerfile, so it comes already installed